# Generics - upper bounded not working as documentation states

Tags: java, generics

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

Above states that:

```
List<? extends Number> a
```

Will work for lists of Number, Integer, Double, anything that is a subclass of number.

But in Java 8, when I try:

```
List<Number a
```

Works with Number and any subclass of it.

Is it me, or generics is overly convoluted and unclear?

Comment: Forgot to mention that it works for mixed lists as well: Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1.1, 3.14)

Comment: I think your question got cut off a bit.  It looks like generics are behaving as the documentation states.  Then what is the problem?

Comment: "To write the method that works on lists of Number and the subtypes of Number, such as Integer, Double, and Float, you would specify List<? extends Number>. The term List<Number> is more restrictive than List<? extends Number> because the former matches a list of type Number only, whereas the latter matches a list of type Number or any of its subclasses."

It states that it works on list of type Number only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<Number>` does *not* mean it cannot contain an `Integer` - you can have an `Integer` in such list as well as a `Double`, even both in the same list.

What you *cannot do* is assign a `List<Integer>` into `List<Number>`. Here's what would happen if you were allowed to do that:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numberList = intList; // suppose this was possible
Number myNum = new Double(...);
numberList.add(myNum); // it's OK to put a Number in List<Number>
Integer myInt = intList.get(0); // myInt now equals myNum, I have Integer that's in fact a Double. Oops.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're writing a generic method that takes in a list of `Number`, since `Number` is the minimal interface you require for the method to work.

If you write the method like this:

```
public void myMethod(List<Number> list) {...}
```

Than this works fine if users pass in a `List<Number>`, but they can not pass in a `List<Integer>` for example, [because generics are *invariant*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). This means that a `List<Integer>` can not be assigned to a `List<Number>`.

---

But let's say that, in your method, you're only taking things out of the list, and care only that they are *any* subclass of `Number` ([i.e. the list is a producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)). For your purposes it would be fine for users to pass in a `List<Integer>`.

This is where the bounded wildcard comes in.

By writing:

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Number> list) {...}
```

You make it okay for users to pass in `List<Integer>`, since it is assignable to `List<? extends Number>`. But if you retrieve an element from the list, you can still be sure that it is a `Number`.

One important difference though, is that you can not add a `Number` to this list any more. Since the list might actually be a `List<Integer>`, adding a `Number` would not be type safe.